# Turning code into a function

Tags: r, normal-distribution, simulation, function

just a quick question to anyone that might know,
i have the following code in R pricing an option:

```
X = 1.05
r = .85
n = 250
nsim = 2000
ctot = 0

for( i in 1:nsim){      # begining of loop
  u1=rnorm(n,0,1)
  u2=rnorm(n,0,1)
  x=u1
  y=r*u1+sqrt(1-r*r)*u2
  x=0.25/sqrt(250)*x + (0.03-0.5*0.25*0.25)/250; y= 0.25/sqrt(250)*y + (0.03-0.5*0.25*0.25)/250

  ShareA = 100*cumprod(exp(x))
  ShareB = 100*cumprod(exp(y))
  c = max(ShareA[n]-X*ShareB[n],0)
  ctot=ctot+c
}                       # end of loop
  c=ctot/nsim   
  c=c*exp(-0.03)
c
```

my question is how can i turn this into a function where i change the correalation, r, to anything i like?
hope this makes sense... essentially the issue is turning this code into a function.
thanks
all suggestions appreciated.

Comment: it would be better if you asked this question on stackoverflow

Comment: Please study An Introduction to R.

Answer (score 0):

To turn this call option into a function that accepts a correlation as an argument:

```
callOptionEval<-function(r=0.85){
  X = 1.05 ; n = 250; nsim = 2000; ctot = 0;

  for( i in 1:nsim){ # begining of loop 
    u1=rnorm(n,0,1); 
    u2=rnorm(n,0,1);
    x=u1; 
    y=r*u1+sqrt(1-r*r)*u2; 
    x=0.25/sqrt(250)*x + (0.03-0.5*0.25*0.25)/250; 
    y= 0.25/sqrt(250)*y + (0.03-0.5*0.25*0.25)/250;

    ShareA = 100*cumprod(exp(x));
    ShareB = 100*cumprod(exp(y));
    c = max(ShareA[n]-X*ShareB[n],0);
    ctot=ctot+c;

  } # end of loop c=ctot/nsim
  c=c*exp(-0.03); 
  return(c)
} 
callOptionEval(0.85)# gives 0 
callOptionEval(0.5)# gives 12.45512
```

Note this code doesn't do the useful stuff that functions should like check that the input is between $(-1, 1)$ etc. This is more of a convenience function for the current user.

Comment: Wonderful thank you ever so much, yes you're right, its more a convenience factor. Thank you again

Comment: if this answer solved your problem marking the question as accepted will close out the question.

Answer (score 0):

`mycorr <- function(x, r, n, nsim, ctot) {`
`Your remaining lines and loops here`
`}`

Use it as 
`mycorr(X = 1.05, r = .85, n = 250, nsim = 2000, ctot = 0)`